# How to set opacity-50 to normal color when you hover it

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to set opacity to normal color when you hover it.
Here's what I've tried.

```
<p class="opacity-50 hover:text-black">Test</p>
```

I've tried the code above but it didn't work.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing the opacity to 100 on hover like this:

```
<p class="opacity-50 text-black hover:opacity-100">Test</p>
```